# python - error with virtualenv in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv

I have installed  virtualenv successfully.The virtualenv's version is 12.0.7.when I want to creat a new enviroment:

```
qixin@qixin:~/文档/myproject$ virtualenv venv
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
ERROR: The executable venv/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/home/qixin/\u6587\u6863/myproject' (should be u'/home/qixin/\u6587\u6863/myproject/venv')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

I have updated the virtualenv with:

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

How to fix it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a unicode problem. Try not to use asian characters in the path.